# No consigo hacer un Scroll suave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap

no puedo hacer un Scroll progresivo desde una animación de texto hacia la sección contacto.

```
div class="wrapper">
    <article id="shufle">
        <div class="container">


        <p class="fading-texts text-center">
            <span>kljljljllj</span> 
            <span>lkjljljljkljljljljljjlj </span>
            <span>lkjkljkljkljljl </span>
            <!-- <span>kjlkkjlkjljlj</span> -->
            <span>Ponte en contacto conmigo  <a class="goto" href="#contact">para una cita. Es rápido y fácil</a></span>
        </p>

        <p class="read-on">
            <a href="#about" class="goto">
            <span class="goDown">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-cog-white"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="htxt">Read on </span>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Desde el span que tiene el enlace con la clase goto, es donde no me funciona tambíen en el parrafo "read-on" tengo un ancla con la misma clase .goto y esta ancla si me funciona bien el scroll. El menú principal tambíen me funciona el scroll progresivo.

el .js lo tengo asi.

```
$('nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 1000);
});


$('.goto').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var offsetTop = $(href).offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: offsetTop}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: te agrego la respuesta correcta

Answer (score 1):

Esto te funcionará...

Hice un sencillo ejemplo añadiendo algunos elementos para simular más o menos lo que pretendes:

```js
$('.goto').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var offsetTop = $(href).offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: offsetTop}, 1000);
});
```

```css
#contact {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 25px;
}
#space {
    height: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Para contactar puedes escribirme a <a href="#contact" class="goto">micorreo@example.com</a></span>

<div id="space"></div>
<div id="contact">
   Contacto:
</div>
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda

Comment: no me funciona, no puedo usar el selector generico $('a').click(function(e){ por que me afecta en otras secciones de la web. he probado poniendo la clase del enlace donde quiero hacer el efecto, he puesto $('goto').click(function(e){ pero no funciona

Comment: @RafaelHernández ya actualicé la respuesta, y es **$('.goto')** y NO **$('goto')**.

Comment: correo.es es potencialmente un dominio válido. En estos casos es mejor usar example.com